# when i use QR code Scanner concept in my project it work when i extends Activity class and give Exception when Extends AppCompactAActivity

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

When I use QR code Scanner  concept by Zxing lib zxingzar-1.1-jar in my project it work.  When I extends Activity class and give Exception when  Extends AppCompactAActivity give illigalArgumentException:

> can only use lower 16 bits for requestCode at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.StartActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java.818)

Comment: Ok. And...? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and revise your question accordingly. It's both illegible and unclear to me (there isn't even a question).

Comment: but AppCompactActivity work in other concept not work only its

Comment: i devlop four apps first time face this problem i change many thing  and three day going on its not solve any one help me